# Difference between simple past and past perfect in one sentence

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, past-perfect, simple-past

And the hatred for Tammany that had been ignited by his idealism was fueled by the wreckage the Tiger had made of his ambitions.

Why passive form of simple past is being used in the middle of the sentence (was fueled)? Would "had been fueled" be correct?

Comment: Where did you find the sentence? Please include the source and link. [Ignite the hatred] vs [fuel the hatred]. Which of the two happened before?

Comment: The fuelling process was probably still extant at the time the sentence focuses on. 'He' still hates Tammany in the narrative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify things by translating into the present. In the present tense, this sentence would be:

> And the hatred for Tammany that has been ignited by his idealism is fueled by the wreckage the Tiger has made of his ambitions.

This is straightforward. And converting it into the past tense is just a matter of replacing simple present with simple past, and present perfect with past perfect. So your sentence is correct as it stands.

Syntactically, *has been fueled* would be OK in this (present) sentence, but the meaning would change: it would mean that the fueling has stopped. So *had been fueled* in your sentence would be syntactically OK, but the meaning would be different. (Having said that, using the past perfect like this three times in a sentence sounds very awkward to my ears; I don't think a native speaker would write such a sentence.)

Comment: Thx. It's a cool trick with the translation into the present.

Answer (score 2):

In an ordinary past-tense narrative, past-form verbs designate events and states **at** Reference Time—the time you are talking about—and past-perfect-form verbs designate events and states **before** Reference Time.

In the sentence you quote, the past-tense main clause speaks of the state at the past Reference Time: 'his' hatred, which at Reference Time is *fueled* by the wreckage. That hatred, however, was originally *ignited* by idealism: a prior time, whose temporal relationship to Reference Time is signalled by the past-perfect.